# Windows 2012: Managing Local Users with a Domain Admin Account

Tags: windows, active-directory

I have two machines with Windows 2012 r2. In one, under Computer Management->System Tools I see a "Local Users and Groups" submenu. In the other, I do not see it. How can two different machines in the same domain present two different sets of capabilities?

The machine in which I can see Local Users and Groups is running Windows Storage Server 2012 R2. It is a Dell box of recent vintage. The machine in which I cannot see Local Users and Groups is running Windows Server 2012 R2. It is a virtual machine.

Using `set` under `cmd`, I can see that the LOGONSERVER is identical. AS well, my USERNAME is identical, as is my USERDOMAIN.

I'm new at this Windows Admin stuff so I really need to wrap my head around Windows user access control. If it's inconsistent, I grow confused!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the servers is a Domain Controller. Domain Controllers don't have local user accounts or security groups.

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect, all Windows servers, even ones promoted to DC will have local users and groups.  However they are managed via the command line.

Net localgroup administrators username /add|/delete

http://www.isunshare.com/windows-2012/create-local-administrator-on-windows-server-2012-r2.html

Comment: +1 for the helpful link

Comment: I think you got that wrong: `net user` and `net localgroup` on a domain controller will show you the *domain* users and *domain* groups. (I just tried it on a DC.)